# Merge two collection inside Vue async using FIrebase onSnapshot() func

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, merge, async-await

I have two collections.
When one of them is updated I need to show the two collections merged to the user.

```
     const listRef = await firebase.firestore()
          .collection("users")
          .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
          .collection("list")
     const customListRef = await firebase.firestore()
          .collection("users")
          .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
          .collection("customList")
```

I'm using this async base function to retrieve datas, but I need to do it for both the collections.

```
     const listRef = await firebase.firestore()
          .collection("users")
          .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
          .collection("list")
        userRef.onSnapshot(snap => {
          this.userLists = []
          snap.forEach(doc => {
            const flower = doc.data()
            product.id = doc.id
            this.userList.push(flower)
          })
        })
    }
```

Is there a way to merge two different collections with only one async/await function?